# Constructing Mongo/Mongoose object with conditions (for unknown number of properties)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

I'm creating an object with Mongoose in Node. I don't know how many of the properties from the model the data I send to the controller will have. I know that in many cases, the data will definitely not have some of the properties in the model. Here is my way of doing this, and I want to hear if there is a better way:

```
function makeContent( user, contentInfo ) {

    var content = new Content({
        user: user,
        stream: req.body.type,
        added: ( new Date() / 1),
        url: req.body.url
    })
    if ( contentInfo.meta.date ) {
        content.date = contentInfo.date
    }
    if ( contentInfo.meta.likes ) {
        content.likes = contentInfo.meta.likes
    }
    if ( contentInfo.meat.dislikes ) {
        content.dislikes = contentInfo.meta.dislikes    
    }

    contend.save()  
}
```

It's a little more tedious because there are actually a dozen more potential values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install underscore :

```
npm install underscore
```

Use underscore's extend() method, which assigns properties from the second object to the first object, and returns the first object.

```
var _ = require('underscore')

function makeContent( user, contentInfo ) {

    var content = new Content(_.extend({
        user: user,
        stream: req.body.type,
        added: ( new Date() / 1),
        url: req.body.url
    }, contentInfo.meta))

    content.save()  
}
```